# How to Install pip for python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I've installed Python 3.7 on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Following this instructions in case it's relevant:

> Download : Python 3.7 from Python Website [1] ,on Desktop and manually
> unzip it, on Desktop Installation : Open Terminal (ctrl +shift+T)
>
> ```
> Go to the Extracted folder
> $ cd ~/Desktop/Python-3.7.0
> $ ./configure
> $ make
> $ sudo make install
> ```
>
> Making Python 3.7 default Python :
>
> ```
> $ sudo vim ~/.bashrc
> press i
> on the last and new line - Type
> alias python= python3.7
> press Esc
> type - to save and exit vim
> :wq
> now type
> $ source ~/.bashrc
> ```

From here: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-upgrade-Python-3-6-to-3-7-in-Ubuntu-18-04

I've downloaded several modules through `pip install module` but when I try to import them, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'xx'`

So I did some research and apparently when used pip to install, it installed in the modules in previous version of Python.
Somewhere (probably a question in SO) I found a suggestion to install the module using `python3.7 -m pip install module` but then I get `/usr/local/bin/python3.7: no module named pip`.

Now I'm stuck, pip is installed, but apparently not for Python 3.7. I'm assuming that if I can install pip for Python 3.7, I can run the pip install command and get the modules I need.
If that is the case, how can I install pip for python 3.7, since it's already installed?

---

This is the best I have come up with:

I have installed python 3.7 successfully and I can install modules using pip (or pip3) but those modules are installed in Python 3.6 (Comes with ubuntu). Therefore I can't import those modules in python 3.7 (get a module not found)

Python 3.7 doesn't recognize pip/pip3, so I can't install through pip/pip3
I need python 3.7

Answer (score 168, accepted):

In general, **don't do this**:

```
pip install package
```

because, as you have correctly noticed, it's not clear what Python version you're installing `package` for.

Instead, if you want to install `package` for Python 3.7, **do this**:

```
python3.7 -m pip install package
```

Replace `package` with the name of whatever you're trying to install.

Took me a surprisingly long time to figure it out, too. The docs about it are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage).

Your other option is to set up a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). Once your virtual environment is active, executable names like `python` and `pip` will point to the correct ones.

Comment: Already tried, output: `/usr/local/bin/python3.7: no module named pip` [Same for pip3]

Comment: Sounds like your Python 3.7 install is missing pip. You could try installing it using: `python3.7 -m ensurepip`. Also, I notice that you installed from source. If the above options don't work for you, then perhaps try installing via apt instead: `apt install python3.7`? The apt package comes with the pip module installed.

Comment: I tried `python3.7 -m ensurepip`, it installed but when I used `python3.7 -m pip install package` got a bunch of errors. Since I was on a VM, I went back before installing python 3.7 and tried `apt install python3.7` and then `python3.7 -m pip install package`. Now everything is running smooth. Thanks!

Comment: please correct your answer. it failed. but this  `python3.7 -m pip install pip` works fine

Comment: You're supposed to replace "package" with the name of the package you're trying to install.

Comment: `Sounds like your Python 3.7 install is missing pip`, do you perhaps mean his python 3.6 is missing pip?

Comment: I just installed `python3.7` on fresh Ubuntu, and met `/usr/local/bin/python3.7: no module named pip`. Preceding command with `sudo apt install python3-pip` fixed the issue.

Comment: Neither this answer, nor ensurepip worked for me. :(

Comment: Edited to add a key missing detail captured in dangel's answer.

Comment: Well I tried to edit it. Not a complete answer without that info, so to all: if you run into the issue I did, apply dangel's answer first. See my answer below for a complete solution.

Comment: this approach is also helping when you need to install e.g. pip3.8

Comment: This also will need `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` cause `python3.7 -m pip install pip` puts pip into `$HOME/.local/`

Comment: `No module named ensurepip` -_-

Answer (score 134):

A quick add-on to [mpenkov's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54758592/895810) (didn't want this to get lost in the comments)

For me, I had to install pip for 3.6 first

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

now you can install python 3.7

```
sudo apt install python3.7
```

and then I could install pip for 3.7

```
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

and as a bonus, to install other modules just preface with

```
python3.7 -m pip install <module>
```

**EDIT 1 (12/2019):**

I know this is obvious for most.  but if you want python 3.8, just substitute `python3.8` in place of `python3.7`

**EDIT 2 (5/2020):**

For those that are able to upgrade, Python 3.8 is available out-of-the-box for Ubuntu 20.04 which was released a few weeks ago.

Comment: Ty! Also calling `pip3.7` seems to work after completing the steps.

Comment: Why is this happening, can anyone shed light on this strange behavior?

Comment: This also will need `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` cause `python3.7 -m pip install pip` puts pip into `$HOME/.local/`

Answer (score 35):

This works for me.

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

Then this command with sudo:

`python3.7 get-pip.py`

Based on [this instruction](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: Need to run the other commands as on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57921046/1541042

Answer (score 22):

I used apt-get to install python3.7 in ubuntu18.04. The installations are as follows.

1. install python3.7

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

2. install pip3. It should be noted that this may install pip3 for python3.6.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

3. change the default of python3 for python3.7. This is where the magic is, which will make the pip3 refer to python3.7.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks ! this is the most complete way, since it covers the fact that your system probably has another python3

Answer (score 11):

To install all currently supported python versions (python 3.6 is already pre-installed) including pip for Ubuntu 18.04 do the following:

To install python3.5 and python3.7, use the deadsnakes ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Install python2.7 via distribution packages:

```
sudo apt install python-minimal  # on Ubuntu 18.04 python-minimal maps to python2.7
```

To install pip use:

```
sudo apt install python-pip  # on Ubuntu 18.04 this refers to pip for python2.7
sudo apt install python3-pip  # on Ubuntu 18.04 this refers to pip for python3.6
python3.5 -m pip install pip # this will install pip only for the current user
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

I used it for setting up a CI-chain for a python project with tox and Jenkins.

Answer (score 9):

Combining the answers from @mpenkon and @dangel, *this* is what worked for me:

1. `sudo apt install python3-pip`
2. `python3.7 -m pip install pip`

Step #1 is required (assuming you don't already have pip for python3) for step #2 to work. It uses pip for Python3.6 to install pip for Python 3.7 apparently.

Comment: One problem here is that `sudo apt install python3-pip` does not guarantee the installation of python3.7, but other python3 versions as well

Comment: That's true, but oddly why it seems to work (I think; not at all a Linux guru). It seems like some type of bootstrap approach is needed since you can't use software you don't have to install software you don't have. In any case it did work for me. Did you run into issues following this approach?

Comment: In the way that it did not installed python 3.7, yes. Definitely the best approach is to use `sudo apt install python3.7` considering Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

When i use `apt install python3-pip`, i get a lot of packages need install, but i donot need them. So,  i DO like this:

```
apt update
apt-get install python3-setuptools
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
rm -f get-pip.py
```

Comment: Raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'` (Python 3.7.15)

Answer (score 3):

The following steps can be used:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
---------
sudo apt-get install python3.7
--------------
 python3.7
-------------
 curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
-----------------
sudo apt install python3-pip
-----------------
sudo apt install python3.7-venv
-----------------
 python3.7 -m venv /home/ubuntu/app
-------------
 cd app   
----------------
 source bin/activate
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install python3.7
 python3.7
 curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt install python3.7-venv
 python3.7 -m venv /home/ubuntu/app
 cd app   ---- source bin/activate

Answer (score 3):

### Install python pre-requisites

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```

### Install python 3.7 (from ppa repository)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.7
```

### Install pip3.7

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

### Create python and pip alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/pip pip /home/your_username/.local/bin/pip3.7 10
```

### Make changes

```
source ~/.bashrc
python --version
pip --version
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who intend to use [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

If you don't already have `pip` for Python 3:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Install `venv` package:

```
sudo apt install python3.7-venv
```

Create virtual environment (which will be bootstrapped with `pip` by default):

```
python3.7 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

To activate the virtual environment, `source` the appropriate script for the current shell, from the `bin` directory of the virtual environment. The appropriate scripts for the different shells are:

bash/zsh – `activate`

fish – `activate.fish`

csh/tcsh – `activate.csh`

For example, if using bash:

```
source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate
```

Optionally, to update `pip` for the virtual environment (while it is activated):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

When you want to deactivate the virtual environment:

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed `pip3` using

```
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

But upon using `pip3` to install other dependencies, it was using python3.6. 
You can check the by typing `pip3 --version`

Hence, I used `pip3` like this (stated in one of the above answers):

```
python3.7 -m pip install <module>
```

or use it like this:

```
python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I made a bash alias for later use in ~/.bashrc file as `alias pip3='python3.7 -m pip'`. If you use alias, don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc` after making the changes and saving it.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply

```
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install python3.7-dev
alias pip3.7="python3.7 -m pip"
```

Now you have the command

```
pip3.7
```

separately from pip3.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.7
```

if all else fails.

Answer (score -2):

`pip3` not `pip`. You can create an alias like you did with `python3` if you like.

Comment: Same issue. `/usr/local/bin/python3.7: no module named pip3`

Comment: in your terminal, type `$ which pip` and `$ which pip3` and see what both of those say.

Comment: `/usr/bin/pip` and `/usr/bin/pip3`

Comment: Okay, what exactly are you typing into the terminal to see the error `no module named pip3` or whatever?

Comment: `python3.7 -m pip3 install psycopg2`. If i just use `pip3 install psycopg2` it downloads the module, but I still can't import it in Python 3.7.

Comment: Did you follow the docs for psycopg2? It looks like it's not as simple as installing from pip: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html

Comment: Psycopg2 was an example, I get the same issue from the other modules, such as ccxt, websockets, django. However if I open python 3.6 terminal (typing `$python3.6`) and import, the modules work. It seems they are installed only for 3.6

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, you are tying to import into 3.7 but it's not working. However, if you import into 3.6 it is working?

Comment: Precisely. And I need 3.7 in this scenario.

Comment: Okay, sounds like pip is not installed for python3.7 and it doesn't know where to find pip. Try `$ python3.7 -m /usr/bin/pip3 install package`.

Comment: The return was `/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named /usr/bin/pip3`