# How to install pip3 for a specific python version

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have python3.7 installed but also python3.4. For example:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 12 2018, 22:25:49) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And:

```
$ python3.7
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How can I install packages to `python3.7` ? Any `pip3` command I use goes to python3.4 and I'm not sure how to install anything for python3.7. Any ideas? Even running something like this doesn't work:

```
$ python3.7 -m ensurepip --upgrade
/usr/bin/python3.7: No module named ensurepip
```

Or:

```
$ sudo python3.7 -m pip install PyMySQL
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install a module using pip for specific python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this may be an appropriate solution for you. But this is what I generally follow. 
Just install Anaconda in your system and create different environments according to your needs.
For your case create two different environments one for Python 3.4.3 and another for Python 3.7 using the following command

```
conda create --name py34 python=3.4.3 and 
conda create --name py37 python=3.7 
//This lines will create two new environments named py34 and py37
```

You then install libraries according to your needs in the respective environment. Now you can work into each environment without interfering with the libraries of the other environment.
To use anaconda kindly follow [Anaconda cheatsheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf). You will get everything that you need.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633657/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18) : It addresses the same issue as yours. In short, try

`python3.7 -m pip install pip`

[Here's a reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage)